# How to make sure journal is indexed in Scopus or not

Tags: indexing, scopus

I have submitted a paper to a Q2 journal last year (2021). But now when I checked the Scopus record it says `Scopus coverage years:from 2018 to 2021`. Does this mean its not indexed now? For some other journal it says `from 20xx to present` at Scopus.

What should I do now? I have also paid the APC fee.

EDIT:
I checked scopus discontinued [list](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/excel_doc/0015/91122/ext_list_January_2022.xlsx) and i cant found it in there. Can you please check this ISSN: 2089-4872. It is available in Scopus Sources October 2021. It is not available in Discontinued titles Jan. 2022. What does this mean. It is quite confusing for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search Scopus for the journal. If you don't find it, it's not indexed.

**Edit:** the journal in question is indexed by Scopus, but it doesn't have any 2022 articles. I'm guessing that's why the Scopus coverage years are only 2018-2021. 2022 articles will be indexed eventually, just not yet.

Comment: I checked scopus discontinued [list](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/excel_doc/0015/91122/ext_list_January_2022.xlsx) and i cant found it in there.  Can you please check this ISSN: 2089-4872. It is available in Scopus Sources October 2021. It is not available in Discontinued titles Jan. 2022. What does this mean. It is quite confusing for me

Comment: @TalhaAnwar what is the name of the journal?

Comment: @TalhaAnwar also, it sounds like the journal is still indexed in Scopus.

Comment: title name: IAES International Journal of Artificial Intelligence.

Comment: @TalhaAnwar I just checked Scopus. This journal is indexed, and by the Cite Score, is not in danger of being delisted either. Looks like this answer is incorrect; I am going to amend it.